# Unable to load StandAlone version of Eclipse MAT (Memory Analyzer Tool)

Tags: eclipse, memory-leaks, mat, heap-dump

I wants to analyze Heap Dump on my local system. So I downloaded 64 bit version of standalone MAT.

But I am not able to launch the MAT. MAT UI is not getting launched when I double click on exe file.

MAT generated error logs under "configuration" directory. AS per the logs, MAT is not able to resolve dependency for "org.eclipse.birt.chart.device.extension". Please see more details below :

```
!SESSION 2016-02-11 03:40:49.831 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.6.0_18
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86

!ENTRY org.eclipse.birt.chart.device.extension 4 0 2016-02-11 03:41:01.810
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.birt.chart.device.extension [24]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.birt.chart.engine; bundle-version="[2.1.0,5.0.0)"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.birt.chart.engine; bundle-version="4.5.0.v201506092134"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.birt.chart.engine [26]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.birt.core; bundle-version="[2.1.0,5.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.birt.core; bundle-version="4.5.0.v201506092134"; singleton:="true"
              org.eclipse.birt.core [28]
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime; bundle-version="[3.2.0,4.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"
                  -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.core.runtime; bundle-version="3.11.0.v20150405-1723"; singleton:="true"
                     org.eclipse.core.runtime [40]
                       Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.jobs; bundle-version="[3.2.0,4.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"
                         -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.core.jobs; bundle-version="3.7.0.v20150330-2103"; singleton:="true"
                            org.eclipse.core.jobs [37]
                              Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.7))"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.birt.chart.device.swt 4 0 2016-02-11 03:41:01.866
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.birt.chart.device.swt [25]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.birt.chart.engine; bundle-version="[2.1.0,5.0.0)"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.birt.chart.engine; bundle-version="4.5.0.v201506092134"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.birt.chart.engine [26]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.birt.core; bundle-version="[2.1.0,5.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.birt.core; bundle-version="4.5.0.v201506092134"; singleton:="true"
              org.eclipse.birt.core [28]
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime; bundle-version="[3.2.0,4.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"
                  -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.core.runtime; bundle-version="3.11.0.v20150405-1723"; singleton:="true"
                     org.eclipse.core.runtime [40]
                       Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.jobs; bundle-version="[3.2.0,4.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"
                         -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.core.jobs; bundle-version="3.7.0.v20150330-2103"; singleton:="true"
                            org.eclipse.core.jobs [37]
                              Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.7))"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.birt.chart.engine 4 0 2016-02-11 03:41:01.867
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.birt.chart.engine [26]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.birt.core; bundle-version="[2.1.0,5.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.birt.core; bundle-version="4.5.0.v201506092134"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.birt.core [28]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime; bundle-version="[3.2.0,4.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.core.runtime; bundle-version="3.11.0.v20150405-1723"; singleton:="true"
              org.eclipse.core.runtime [40]
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.jobs; bundle-version="[3.2.0,4.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"
                  -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.core.jobs; bundle-version="3.7.0.v20150330-2103"; singleton:="true"
                     org.eclipse.core.jobs [37]
                       Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.7))"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.birt.chart.engine.extension 4 0 2016-02-11 03:41:01.867
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.birt.chart.engine.extension [27]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.birt.chart.engine; bundle-version="[2.1.0,5.0.0)"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.birt.chart.engine; bundle-version="4.5.0.v201506092134"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.birt.chart.engine [26]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.birt.core; bundle-version="[2.1.0,5.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.birt.core; bundle-version="4.5.0.v201506092134"; singleton:="true"
              org.eclipse.birt.core [28]
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime; bundle-version="[3.2.0,4.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"
                  -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.core.runtime; bundle-version="3.11.0.v20150405-1723"; singleton:="true"
                     org.eclipse.core.runtime [40]
                       Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.jobs; bundle-version="[3.2.0,4.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"
                         -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.core.jobs; bundle-version="3.7.0.v20150330-2103"; singleton:="true"
                            org.eclipse.core.jobs [37]
                              Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.7))"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.birt.core 4 0 2016-02-11 03:41:01.868
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.birt.core [28]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime; bundle-version="[3.2.0,4.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.core.runtime; bundle-version="3.11.0.v20150405-1723"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.core.runtime [40]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.jobs; bundle-version="[3.2.0,4.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.core.jobs; bundle-version="3.7.0.v20150330-2103"; singleton:="true"
              org.eclipse.core.jobs [37]
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.7))"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.contenttype 4 0 2016-02-11 03:41:01.869
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.core.contenttype [30]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.7))"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
```

I am using 64 bit version of JDK 1.6.0_18 on 64 bit OS.

Can anyone please suggest some solution to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line:

```
Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.7))"
```

is saying you need to be using Java 7 (or 8)

You can specify a specific JVM to use for Eclipse MAT by editing the 'MemoryAnalyzer.ini' file in the install directory and adding the lines

```
-vm
path to Java 7 java
```

You must add this **above** the '-vmargs' line. You must put '-vm' on a separate line from the path.

Comment: Add details on specifying a path in the ini file to the answer.

Comment: I am using JDK 1.6.0_18. Thing is that, so many other application are running on my system which is dependent on JDK6. So I will not be able to change the JVM.  But It worked for me using command prompt. I changed the JDK using "set path.." in command prompt and and try to open MAT using that command prompt. That worked for me !! Thank You for Quick help greg !.

Comment: I removed my previous comment. I was open to open the MAT using command prompt but it took more time to open. So, It is working now.

Answer (score 0):

The -vm flag was not fixing the problem for me.

I needed to update the version of java on my path; `readlink -e $(which java)` was showing jdk6.